# How can I find the element clicked on inside a jQuery handler?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to do a specific action on the clicked element if an argument is passed in the on click method in jQuery. When I try to access `this` it's referencing the entire window instead of the clicked on element. How would I access the clicked on element in the handler?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var myfunction = function(action) {
  var content;
  var $this = $(this);
if(action === "one") {
  $(".output").text("clicked on one");
  $this.addClass("one");
 } 
if(action === "two") {
 $(".output").text("clicked on two");
 $this.addClass("two");
  }
};
$("#button").on("click", function(event) {
 myfunction("one");
});

$("#button2").on("click", function(event) {
  myfunction("two");
});
```

I set up an example on jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/bipafi/edit?html,js,output). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ypxs27wd/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

JQUERY WAY:

Within your jquery click event handlers you have the `event` object.  It has a property called `target` which is what you're looking for.

Change this: `$this.addClass("one");`

To this: `$(event.target).addClass("one");`

You can also do this: `event.target.className = "one"`

And do for "two" as well obviously...

VANILLA WAY:

You can just pass in an extra argument representing your clicked element.

```
var myfunction = function(action, element) {
  var content;
if(action === "one") {
  $(".output").text("clicked on one");
  $(element).addClass("one");
  // or event.target.className = "one"
 } 
if(action === "two") {
 $(".output").text("clicked on two");
 $(element).addClass("two");
 // or event.target.className = "two"
  }
};
$("#button").on("click", function(event) {
 myfunction("one", this);
});

$("#button2").on("click", function(event) {
  myfunction("two", this);
});
```

Comment: @CompMike: Good to hear...lemme get that check mark brotha :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
$("#button2").on("click", function(event) {
  myfunction.call(this, "two");
});
```

or store the action as an attribute on your element, bind your handler directly and query the attribute.

```
var myfunction = function() {
    var content;
    var $this = $(this);
    var action = $this.attr('data-action');
    if (action === "one") {
        $(".output").text("clicked on one");
        $this.addClass("one");
    } else if (action === "two") {
        $(".output").text("clicked on two");
        $this.addClass("two");
    }
};
$("#button2").on("click", myfunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

this refers to the object the function belongs to, in your case the function belongs to the window object or global object, the 'this' keyword behaves differently depending on how you use your function, if you use it as a constructor function for example (with the new keyword) 'this' will be bound to new object being constructed, and when the function is used as an event handler this will be set to the event the element the event fired from.
see :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this  for more information.

you need to change your code and do something like this:

```
$(".button").on("click",function(){
   var $this = $(this) //refers to the event it was fired from (button object)
$(".output").text("You clicked on "+$this.text());      
});
```

i used classes instead of ids to target any button that's clicked

an example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fvacbd9u/